# Replace whole text in a text file using command prompt?

Tags: text, command-line, str-replace

Is there a way to replace whole text from a text file using command prompt? As far as I have come across is about replacing part of a text through find and replace. Is there a way to replace the complete texts from text file?

```
powershell -Command "(gc Pro.txt) -replace 'One', 'Two' | Out-File -encoding ASCII Pro.txt"
```

Comment: Like copying a new file on top of the existing one? And/or an equivalent to `echo >` instead of `echo >>` in Linux, or `copy con` in DOS?

Comment: @B.Go in Windows, completely replacing the whole text in the text file.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, the way to replace whole text is:

`@echo myText > Pro.txt`